# SHM with spring moving at constant velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

How does vertical SHM work when the spring is moving.
In school, we've all learnt the basic vertical SHM spring attached to block setup. However, how does this same setup work in the case that the spring is moving. Imagine that someone is pulling the top of the string with a constant velocity upward. How would the block move? How does this affect the SHM angular velocity, amplitude, equilibrium position, etc?

Moreover, how would one find the position of the block after $t$ seconds?

Comment: What did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: This question is primarily conceptual, although the final two questions are perhaps too quantitative for our homework policy.

Comment: In the ground frame all you need to do is $v_{\text{top of spring}}$ velocity to the static spring oscillatory shm $v_{\rm shm}$ velocity, and $v_{\text{top of spring}}\times \rm time $ to the static oscillatory shm displacement from the static shm equilibrium position.

Answer (score 1):

Since the top of the spring is moving upwards with a constant velocity, we can work in a reference frame in which the top of the spring is stationary (and the ground is moving *downwards* with a constant velocity) without changing any of the laws of physics or introducing any "pseudoforces".

In this reference frame the block on the end of the spring initially remains on the ground, which is moving downwards with a speed of, say, $v$. So the extension $x$ of the spring at time $t$ is $x=vt$ (assuming that at $t=0$ the spring has zero extension).

The block stays on the ground until the extension of the spring $x$ reaches the point when the tension in the spring $T=kx$ equals the weight of the block $mg$. At this point the extension of the spring is $x_0 = \frac {mg} k$, and this happens after $t_0=\frac {x_0} v$ seconds.

At this point the block is in equilibrium (the two forces acting on it are equal and opposite) *but* it is still moving downwards with speed $v$. Because of its inertia it will continue to move downwards, the spring continues to extend, the tension $T$ increases, and the block slows down, eventually stops, and then is pulled back towards its equilibrium position $x_0$. Because the ground continues to move downwards with speed $v$, the block will never be in contact with the ground again, and we can ignore the ground from now onwards.

If we ignore air resistance, the block is now executing SHM about its equilibrium position $x_0$. Each time it passes through $x_0$ it has speed $v$. Given this information, you can find the equation of motion of the block from $t=t_0$ onwards.

Comment: Great explanation. To clarify when you say "Each time it passes through 0 it has speed " is that in the moving frame or inertial frame?

Comment: @WilliamHarvey Everything is relative to the top of the spring.